# Troubleshooting "descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'"

Tags: python, datetime

In my code I ask the user for a date in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`.

```
currentdate = raw_input("Please enter todays date in the format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
day,month,year = currentdate.split('/')
today = datetime.date(int(year),int(month),int(day))
```

This returns the error

> TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

if I remove the `int()` then I end up with the same error only it says it received a `'str'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 71):

It seems that you have imported `datetime.datetime` module instead of `datetime`. This should work though:

```
import datetime
currentdate = raw_input("Please enter todays date in the format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
day,month,year = currentdate.split('/')
today = datetime.date(int(year),int(month),int(day))
```

..or this:

```
from datetime import date
currentdate = raw_input("Please enter todays date in the format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
day,month,year = currentdate.split('/')
today = date(int(year),int(month),int(day))
```

Answer (score 57):

Do you import like this?

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Then you must change it to look like this:

```
import datetime
```

Explanation: In the first case you are effectively calling `datetime.datetime.date()`, a method on the object `datetime` in the module `datetime`. In the later case you create a new `date()` object with the constructor `datetime.date()`.

Alternatively, you can change the import to:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
```

and then construct with `date(y,m,d)` (without the `datetime.` prefix).

Comment: This is very confusing... what do you do when you need to use both??

Comment: Uh, what do you mean with “both”? You have access to the whole module content, when you use `import datetime` (e.g., what you mostly want, the `datetime` class there, under the name `datetime.datetime`).

Comment: Whoever organized this library in Python did not think it through.  There's no way this isn't extremely confusing to inexperienced Python programmers.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I stumbled over it, too, when I started using Python.

Answer (score 14):

if you already have

```
from datetime import datetime
```

then you can construct like so:

```
christmas = datetime(2013,12,25)
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use both datetime and datetime.datetime.
Write the imports like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt

time_1 = datetime.strptime('17:00:00', '%H:%M:%S')
time_1 = dt.time(time_1.hour, time_1.minute,  time_1.second)
```

Answer (score 7):

I can reproduce the error if I do

```
from datetime import *
```

It goes away when I do

```
import datetime
```

So check your imports.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the `datetime` reference the object and not the module. You probably did have the following code (probably more complex):

```
from datetime import datetime
currentdate = raw_input("Please enter todays date in the format dd/mm/yyyy: ")
day,month,year = currentdate.split('/')
today = datetime.date(int(year),int(month),int(day))
```

You are thus calling the `date` method of the `datetime` class instead of calling the `date` function of the `datetime` module.

You can print the `datetime` object to see if this is really the case:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> print datetime
<module 'datetime' (built-in)>
>>> print datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
0001-01-01
>>> datetime = datetime.datetime
>>> print datetime
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> print datetime.date(1, 1, 1)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    print datetime.date(1, 1, 1)
TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

> TypeError: descriptor 'date' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'int'

This is because you have used variables like year, month, day.

Use something like this:

```
year1, month1, day1 =  [int(d) for d in startDate.split('-')]
print(date(year1, month1, day1))
```

and it will work.

Answer (score -3):

The error suggest's your import looks fine. Instead, while doing an operation using datetime, make sure the values are converted to datetime format first.

use **pandas.to_datetime** to do the same, before you use any operation on the same.