# TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I've just encountered this issue, and couldn't find a reasonable answer for it on the front page of Google. It's similar to [this question asked in 2011](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619489/troubleshooting-descriptor-date-requires-a-datetime-datetime-object-but-rec), but for a newer version of Python, which results in a different error message.

What is causing these `TypeError`s?

#### Integers

```py
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime.date(2021, 3, 2)
```

Results in the error:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

#### Strings

Similarly, replacing the integers with strings also gives the same error:

```py
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime.date("2021", "3", "2")
```

Gives:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

#### Lists

And using a list gives the same error:

```py
import datetime
my_date = datetime.datetime.date([2021, 3, 2])
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object
```

Similarly, using `from datetime import datetime` and `datetime.date` will result in the following error messages respectively:

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

```
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'list' object
```

Comment: since the [datetime.datetime.date()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) method actually doesn't take any arguments at all, the error message seems confusing indeed

Comment: @MrFruppes Yeah, that's what threw me. I don't program in Python so often, so that error message pop up didn't really indicate to me that I was trying to call a method on a class which hadn't been instantiated.

Comment: "It's similar to this question asked in 2011, but for a newer version of Python, which results in a different error message." That doesn't make it a different problem, and therefore doesn't make it a different question. The answers are the same: the code tries to call an instance method from the class, such that `self` is wrong. This version is probably better, though, because it's good to keep up to date.

Comment: That said, the same problem can be caused by *any* instance method of *any* class, and a quick search implies that it is asked a fair bit, with no clear canonical. (This *would* be it, since it's the most popular by far of the questions showing the exact new error message; but it isn't general enough.)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're correct that the general case pops up a fair bit, but I think this specific case is one people hit fairly often. 2 years ago I dropped my error message into Google and nothing came up, so I wrote this Q+A.

Comment: The downside of writing a generic Q+A is that the advice would be generic too. For it to be easily searchable, we'd need a massive list of error messages in the question. I think the number of error messages is close to the maximum number which is reasonable to include in a question.

Comment: In fact, while any instance method of any class could have "the same problem", it's only reported this way for builtins. I'm still figuring out a course of action in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247434/python-canon-discussion (among many other issues).

Answer (score 86, accepted):

#### Solution:

```
import datetime
my_date = datetime.date(2021, 3, 2)
```

or

```
from datetime import date
my_date = date(2021, 3, 2)
```

#### Why?

The issue is that [`datetime.datetime.date()` is a method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date) on a [`datetime.datetime` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime). We were  confusing the `datetime` module with the `datetime.datetime` class.

What we're really looking for is the [`datetime.date()` constructor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date).

Comment: Thanks! For this reason it's important to always include import statements in code examples (here and in documentations).