# Python 3 - datetime Class/module Error in VS Code (Windows)

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, python-datetime

I am trying to print a simple statement that will show today's date. But no matter how I try, I keep getting the same error. Here are some examples:

```
    import datetime
    
    today = datetime.datetime.date.today()
    print(today)
```

I've also tried:

```
    from datetime import datetime

    today = datetime.date.today()
    print(today)
```

Either way, this is the error message I get in the terminal:

"AttributeError: partially initialized module 'datetime' has no attribute 'date' (most likely due to a circular import)"

Any advice? I'm going nuts and yet, it should be so simple! @_@

Comment: Just do this `datetime.datetime.today()`

Comment: Do you have a file called datetime.py or date.py in same folder?

Comment: related : https://stackoverflow.com/q/66431493/10197418 - have a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) with attention to the difference between module, classes and methods of those classes.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did try 'datetime.datetime.today()' before to no avail. However, I did not consider the file name! What a dummie! Thank you for catching that and your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your file name is the same as the package:
Change it for antoher name, like  'Time_example.py'