# Trying to make a countdown, where you input the the date

Tags: python, countdown

Trying to make a countdown, where you input the date:

```
from datetime import datetime

year = int(input('Enter a year: '))
month = int(input('Enter a month: '))
day = int(input('Enter a day: '))

date = datetime.date(year, month, day)

countdown = date - datetime.now()
print(countdown)
```

The error is:

```
  line 7, in <module>
    date = datetime.date(year, month, day) 
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `date = datetime(year, month, day)`... The module `datetime` have the classes `date` and `datetime`. You are trying to access the descriptor `date` of the class `datetime` in the module `datetime`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431493/typeerror-descriptor-date-for-datetime-datetime-objects-doesnt-apply-to-a)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
date = datetime(year, month, day).date()

countdown = date - datetime.now().date()

print(countdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type.

*A datetime object is a single object containing all the information from a date object and a time object.
A date object represents a date (year, month and day) in an idealized calendar, the current Gregorian calendar indefinitely extended in both directions.*

Try adding **.date()** to *datetime* object.

e.g.: **datetime(year, month, day).date()**