# TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'datetime.date' object

Tags: python, date, datetime

So I am trying to convert a `YYYY-MM-DD` string into a English format as: `WEEKDAY DDth MONTH YEAR`
However I am having issue converting the string into a date format which I believe is `YYYY, MM, DD`.

Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
[...]
def getHumanDate(rawdate):
    the_date = date(int(rawdate[0:4]), int(rawdate[6:7]), int(rawdate[9:10]))

    weekday = (datetime.date(the_date).strftime('%A'))
    month = (datetime.date(the_date).strftime('%B'))

    year = int(rawdate[0:4])
    day = int(rawdate[9:10])

    english = weekday + " " + day + "th of " + month + " " + year
    return english
```

I am getting a `TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'datetime.date' object` error which I frankly can't wrap my head around.

Any help would be appreciated!
Cheers

**Edit:** Here is a working example using the Calendar library, although completely different, it works!

```
import calendar
[...]
def getHumanDate(rawdate):
    int_year = int(rawdate[0:4])
    int_month = int(rawdate[6:7])
    int_day = int(rawdate[9:10])

    week_days=["Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"]
    months=["", "January","February","March","April","May","June","July", "August","September","October","November","December"]

    weekday = calendar.weekday(int_year, int_month, int_day)

        
    english = week_days[weekday] + " " + str(int_day) + "th of " + months[int_month] + " " + str(int_year)
    return English
```

Comment: whats the exact input?

Comment: it would be instance 2021-12-19

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431493/typeerror-descriptor-date-for-datetime-datetime-objects-doesnt-apply-to-a)

Answer (score 2):

If you use the strptime function from datetime you get the added advantage of implicit validation of the parameter being pass to your function. Therefore, I suggest this:

```
from datetime import datetime

dsuffix = [None, 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'th', 'st']
def getHumanDate(date): # parameter is expect in ISO format YYYY-MM-DD
    d = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    a = datetime.strftime(d, '%A')
    b = datetime.strftime(d, '%B %Y')
    return f'{a} {d.day}{dsuffix[d.day]} {b}'

for i in range(1, 32):
    d = f'2021-12-{i}'
    print(getHumanDate(d))
```

Comment: see also [Ordinal numbers replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9647202/10197418)

Comment: @MrFuppes I did look at that and it's very clever but less efficient than a straight lookup due to all the calculations it has to make. Concise isn't always best

Comment: Yes, named lambdas aren't exactly PEP8 either... direct lookup on the other might be most efficient, but readability suffers as well imho, as long as you don't hide the lookup table itself from the reader of the code

Comment: In conclusion I think I'll have a separate column in my database for  "human readable date" instead of doing this every single time it loads a date....