# Calculating days between multiple dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am attempting to calculate the days, weeks, or months between different dates. I am using this calculation to manipulate a dataframe and show graphs over time (bar charts, line graphs, etc). I am attempting the use the following code to do so:

```
       userdate = input("Input Start Date Here (YYYY-MM-DD) Or Type All For Entire Networking History: ")

startyear = userdate[0:4]
startmonth = userdate[5:7]
startday = userdate[8:10]

endyear = userenddate[0:4]
endmonth = userenddate[5:7]
endday = userenddate[8:10]

#year month day format
barstartdate = datetime.date(int(startyear),int(startmonth),int(startday))
#year month day format
barenddate = datetime.date(int(endyear),int(endmonth),int(endday))
#delta time
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
#iterate over range of dates
while (barstartdate <= barenddate):
    print(barstartdate, end="\n")
    barstartdate += delta
```

userdate and userenddate are user inputted values for dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD. However, when I run this code, I get the following error message:

TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Comment: You should be able to directly convert the date without having to split it. `datetime.datetime.strptime(userdate, '%Y-%m-%d')`. Try using that first and go from there.

Comment: That code works as intended on my machine. Are your sure your `userdate` and `userenddate` are as expected? (Since you didn't provide a [mre], hard to say)

Comment: I just updated the original post with the userdate and userenddate inputs. The code suggested by @dakdad is not running on my machine, it is saying that datetime.datetime has no attribute datetime and when I change it to datetime.date.strptime it says the method descriptor has no attribute strptime

Comment: @chrslg, just added an example of userdate

Comment: What that suggests is that you have assigned a value like `datetime = 77` so that `datetime` is no longer a module.

Comment: @sw4ps I was expecting a [mre], that is without any `input`. With an example `userdate="2021-11-05"` for example. Just to be sure we run the exact same code in the exact same context (there is not need to have your actual code with `input` here, unless you suspect it is your usage of `input` that is problematic).

Comment: Note that code from @dakdad works fine also. Except that it returns a datetime not a date as yours. But just `datetime.datetime.strptime(userdate, '%Y-%m-%d').date()` should solve that if that is the problem.

Comment: But @TimRoberts comment is probably the kind of problem you really have. Your code works fine here. Ergo the problem is not in your code, but it what you did before this code, that you did not post (like, as I suggested, what you put in `userdate`, or, as he suggested more realisticly, since it matches the error message, what you did to `datetime` before).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431493/typeerror-descriptor-date-for-datetime-datetime-objects-doesnt-apply-to-a)

Comment: @chrslg I apologize for the trouble but the suggestions above are still not working on my machine. I checked to make sure I have nothing defined as datetime. The only time I used date is import datetime, from datetime import date and today = date.today(). Does this help at all as to what the issue could be?

Comment: @chrslg additionally, when I input a date I input something like 2023-06-01

Comment: Nope, my last comment (the one pointing to another question) cancel my previous one. You didn't overwrite `datetime`, that is not the problem. The problem is simply that `datetime` in your case is not the module `datetime` that has a `date` constructor` `datetime.date`, but the `datetime` class of that module, that also have a `date` method, but that `date` method is something else, that does not build a date, and need not 3 integers.

Comment: So, in short, you are calling `datetime.datetime.date(2021,11,20)` which raises this error, instead of calling `datetime.date(2021,11,20)` which would work.

Comment: And you are doing so because you probably imported not the `datetime module`, with `import datetime` but the datetime class directly as `datetime`, with `from datetime import datetime`. So, @TimRoberts was almost right: the problem is that `datetime` is not a module here.

Comment: Note: hence the importance of using [mre]. As several of us pointed out, it is hard to understand what is the problem when we don't have the context. The problem was not in the code you posted (which, again, works fine here), but in the code you didn't post (namely the way you import datetime).

Comment: And, btw, I am here only repeating what is in the link I posted.

Comment: Lastly that is likely the reason why dakdad code wasn't working neither: if `datetime` is not the module, but the `datetime` class that is in this module (what would be called `datetime.datetime` unless the class is imported directly), then `datetime.datetime.strptime` does not exist, since it would be `datetime.datetime.datetime.strptime` in your case, and there is no such thing as `datetime.datetime.datetime`.

Comment: @chrslg thank you. My only issue here is that I have a piece of code that relies on today's date. The way I was getting today's date is "from datetime import date", then doing today = date.today(). Is there a way to work around this by only importing datetime?

Comment: If THAT were the case, then `datetime` would be undefined.  Of course you can do `import datetime` / `today = datetime.date.today()`, but this is not the root of your current problem.

Comment: @TimRoberts this works! Thank you all so much for the help, I am new to Python and still learning to put everything together. I thought for sure something was wrong with my code, not the way I was importing things :/

Comment: @sw4ps You can `from datetime import date, timedelta` and then use `date(2021,11,20)` and `timedelta(days=1)` to create date and timedelta. Or you can `import datetime`, and then use `datetime.date(2021,11,10)` and `datetime.timedelta(days=1)`. You just can't mix both. And for example `from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta` then calling `datetime.date(2021,11,20)` would lead to your exact error. Because then you are not calling the class `date` of module `datetime`, but the method `date` of the class `datetime` of module `datetime`.

Comment: Just try it. `import datetime`. Then compare result of `datetime.date(2021,11,20)` and of `datetime.datetime.date(2021,11,20)`. That is a very simple problem. Just made confusing to understand because of homonyms: both `datetime` and `date` symbol, and even the `datetime.date` expression have different meaning here. `datetime` is both the module name, and the name of a class of that module. `date` is both the name of a class of that module and of a method of `datetime` class. So `datetime.date` is both the name of the class date of module datetime and of the method date of class datetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Hope this is it cause it is not letting me comment with low reputation.

I think you're importing incorrectly the module with
`from datetime import datetime` instead of `import datetime`

So try with this:

```
import datetime

userdate = input("Enter userdate: ")
userenddate = input("Enter userenddate: ")


startyear = userdate[0:4]
startmonth = userdate[5:7]
startday = userdate[8:10]

endyear = userenddate[0:4]
endmonth = userenddate[5:7]
endday = userenddate[8:10]

#year month day format
barstartdate = datetime.date(int(startyear),int(startmonth),int(startday))
#year month day format
barenddate = datetime.date(int(endyear),int(endmonth),int(endday))
#delta time
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
#iterate over range of dates
while (barstartdate <= barenddate):
    print(barstartdate, end="\n")
    barstartdate += delta
```

Output:

```
Enter userdate: 1993-05-05
Enter userenddate: 1993-05-10
1993-05-05
1993-05-06
1993-05-07
1993-05-08
1993-05-09
1993-05-10
```

Finally you should probably check @dakdad method to format strings:

```
import datetime

userdate = input("Enter userdate: ")
date_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(userdate, '%Y-%m-%d')
print(date_obj)
```

Output:

```
Enter userdate: 1993-05-06
1993-05-06 00:00:00
```

Comment: Or at least that's how I stumbled with the "TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object" by using "from datetime import datetime"

Comment: No, sorry, that's not it.  `from datetime import datetime` results in `datetime` being a class.  The error clearly says that `datetime` is an `int`.  Your code won't do that.  I suggest you delete before this is downvoted.

Comment: I don't get it. Aren't both errors (the one I got and his) the same? Saying that they don't apply to an int object?

Comment: Yes, but doing `from datetime import datetime` will absolutely not produce that error.

Comment: It does bring up this error and I believe it's because `datetime.datetime.date()` takes as an argument a datetime object and not an int object and spits only the date (ex. 1993-01-05 00:05:00 --> 1993-01-05). You also need to differentiate datetime and date objects as you can exclude the time part and only keep the date. (BTW I don't know if they're called datetime and date as you strip it in many parts but that's how I differentiate them)

Comment: Because he was trying to use `datetime.date()` which takes a year, a month and a day which can be int objects.