# Can't run flask api. TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Let me start by saying that I am very much a beginner at this kind of stuff.

I ran an analysis on precipitation and would like to create a Flask API that Converts the query results from your precipitation analysis of the last 12 months of data to a dictionary using date as the key and prcp as the value and returns the JSON representation of your dictionary. I was successful at creating the API to Return a JSON list of stations from the dataset.

This is what I have now:

```
# Import the dependencies.
import numpy as np

import sqlalchemy
import datetime
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, func

from flask import Flask, jsonify 

#################################################
# Database Setup
#################################################
engine = create_engine ("sqlite:///Resources/hawaii.sqlite")

# reflect an existing database into a new model
Base = automap_base()

# reflect the tables
Base.prepare(engine, reflect =True)

# Save references to each table
Measurement = Base.classes.measurement
Station = Base.classes.station

# Create our session (link) from Python to the DB

#################################################
# Flask Setup
#################################################
app = Flask(__name__)



#################################################
# Flask Routes
#################################################
@app.route("/")
def Hello():
    """Availble API routes."""
    return (
        f"Available Routes:<br/>"
        f"/api/v1.0/precipitation<br/>"
        f"/api/v1.0/stations<br/>"
        f"/api/v1.0/tobs<br/>"
        f"/api/v1.0/start (enter as YYYY-MM-DD)<br/>"
        f"/api/v1.0/start/end(enter as YYYY-MM-DD)<br/>"
    )
@app.route("/api/v1.0/precipitation")
def precipitation():
    session = Session(engine)
    
    last_date = session.query(func.max(Measurement.date)).scalar()
    
    last_date = datetime.ddatetime.strptime(last_date, '%Y-%m-%d').date()
    
    one_year_ago = last_date - datetime.timedelata(days=365)
    
    precipitation_data = session.query(Measurement.date, Measurement.prcp).filter(Measurement.date >= one_year_ago).all()
    
    session.close()
    
    precipitation_dict = {date: prcp for date, prcp in precipitation_data}
    
    return jsonify(precipitation_dict)
```

Here is the analysis I ran in jupyter notebook.

```
# Design a query to retrieve the last 12 months of precipitation data and plot the results. 
# Starting from the most recent data point in the database. 

# Calculate the date one year from the last date in data set.
year_to_date = dt.date( 2017, 8, 23)-dt.timedelta(days=365)
print('Query Date:', year_to_date)

# Perform a query to retrieve the data and precipitation scores
precip = session.query(Measurement.date,func.max(Measurement.prcp)).filter(func.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', Measurement.date) 
                                                                           > year_to_date).group_by(Measurement.date).all()

# Save the query results as a Pandas DataFrame. Explicitly set the column names
precip_df = pd.DataFrame(precip, columns= ['date', 'prcp'])
precip_df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
precip_df.head(10)

# Sort the dataframe by date
precip_df.sort_values('date')

# Use Pandas Plotting with Matplotlib to plot the data
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20,10)
precip_df.plot(linewidth=2, alpha =1, rot=0,
              xticks=(0,60,120,180,240,300,365),
              color='xkcd:blue')
plt.xlim(-7,380)
plt.ylim(-.6,8)
plt.yticks(size=14)
plt.xticks(fontsize=14)
plt.legend('',frameon=False)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize=16, color='black', labelpad=20)
plt.ylabel('Precipitation (in)', fontsize=16, color='black',labelpad=20)
plt.title('Daily Precipitation for One Year, Honolulu, Hawaii', fontsize =20, pad=40)

plt.show()
```

```
[2023-06-23 12:39:52,178] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/v1.0/precipitation [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/Fowler/Desktop/SQLAlchemy-Challenge/SurfsUp/Starter_Code 9/app.py", line 57, in precipitation
TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Jun/2023 12:39:52] "GET /api/v1.0/precipitation HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431493/typeerror-descriptor-date-for-datetime-datetime-objects-doesnt-apply-to-a for this kind of error message

Comment: After `last_date = session.query(func.max(Measurement.date)).scalar()`, try `print(type(last_date))`. Is it an `int` or a `datetime.date`?

Comment: Also, `datetime.ddatetime.strptime` should be `datetime.strptime`. And `datetime.timedelata` should be `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: descriptor 'date' for 'datetime.datetime' objects doesn't apply to a 'int' object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66431493/typeerror-descriptor-date-for-datetime-datetime-objects-doesnt-apply-to-a)